# c# Min Max of the last 26 results causing Problems

Tags: c#, max, min

Hi Guys im despairing on the following problem I need the Min and Max Values of the last 26 results from 2 values ive got in a csv called "MyCotDataList". After some research i tried it this way:

```
 MyCotDataList.Add(new COTData_Obj
                {
                    Time =  DateTime.Parse(split[0]), 
                    CN = double.Parse(split[5]) - double.Parse(split[6]),
                }); 


                var last26CnValues = MyCotDataList
                    .AsEnumerable()
                        .Reverse()
                        .Take(26)
                          .Select(x => x.CN)
                        .ToArray();

                MyCotDataList.Add(new COTData_Obj
                {

                 Min = last26CnValues.Min(),
                 Max = last26CnValues.Max(),
                }
                );
```

but now instead of propper numbers in the output, i now get a zero every second value i return. Causing a Line on a chart i create with the data to zigzag arround.

If i /**/ out

```
      /*          var last26CnValues = MyCotDataList
                    .AsEnumerable()
                        .Reverse()
                        .Take(26)
                          .Select(x => x.CN)
                        .ToArray();

                MyCotDataList.Add(new COTData_Obj
                {

                 Min = last26CnValues.Min(),
                 Max = last26CnValues.Max(),
                }
                );  */
```

its displaying CN properly
if i keep it in its zigzaging again.
I dont get any compiling errors it simply doesnt do what i intended it to which is obviously due to my lack of skill in c#.

Can you please help me to fix the problem or give me some hints where i screwed up? :D
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Debug your code using the **[Outstanding Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: Did you debug your code and inspect the values in variables ?

Comment: Yes i did :( i dont get compiling errors and the values in the variables are correct until i insert the second part of the code. I edited my original post to make it a little bit clearer. The Problem must be in that part but i really dont get what is wrong there in my logic.

Comment: Can you add an example of the format of the data in the file?

Comment: here's an [IMG](https://i.imgur.com/E0DGc9T.jpg) of the CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this part of the code adds a new `COTData_Obj` object into your list, where the `CN` values is zero. Because you don't set the `CN` and it is 0 by default. And the previously added object has `Min` and `Max` zero, because you don't set these.

```
MyCotDataList.Add(new COTData_Obj
{
    Min = last26CnValues.Min(),
    Max = last26CnValues.Max(),
}
```

You should set it to the object already in the list. I guess this should work

```
COTData_Obj row = new COTData_Obj
                {
                    Time =  DateTime.Parse(split[0]), 
                    CN = double.Parse(split[5]) - double.Parse(split[6]),
                };
MyCotDataList.Add(row); 


                var last26CnValues = MyCotDataList
                    .AsEnumerable()
                        .Reverse()
                        .Take(26)
                          .Select(x => x.CN)
                        .ToArray();

                row.Min = last26CnValues.Min();
                row.Max = last26CnValues.Max();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That finally fixed the problem with the 0 values! But if i look at the Chart now it seems that it doesnt really look for the lowest/highest values in the last 26 entrys of the csv. Heres an [img](https://i.imgur.com/FhCNAas.jpg) of what im seeing. The blue line is CN green is Max and red is Min. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: Put whole loop code here, please. It looks like you have min and max from future, not from the past.

Comment: The complete loop is too long to post it as a comment heres a link to Github where you can see the complete code: https://github.com/GrainCracker/CoT-Data-Oszilator-for-NT8/blob/master/CotOszi%201.0

Comment: The Loop starts at Line 729

Comment: Problem might be this:
```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlotsToSet - 2; i++)
            {
                //  Print(cotDataList[i].Min); 
                Values[3][i] = cotDataList[i].Min;
            }
```
Index 0 sets value to current bar. Thus you might want to reverse the assignments:
```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlotsToSet - 2; i++)
            {
                //  Print(cotDataList[i].Min); 
                Values[3][i] = cotDataList[numberOfPlotsToSet - 2 - 1 - i].Min;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i tried this aproach but it messes up the data completly min is sometimes higher than the current value and so on :(